# Select cell on scroll in collectionView by default

Tags: ios, swift, offset, collectionview, cgpoint

I have a custom collection view layout which seems to produce some bugs. Or maybe I'm missing something. Layout looks like this and it's from [here](https://github.com/ro6lyo/UICollectionViewGallery):

[image]

My problem is I can't pass the indexPath of the centered cell to pink button, call of `centerCellIndexPath` produces nil. I also tried to preselect the cell in the layout itself, like so:

```
 override open func targetContentOffset(forProposedContentOffset proposedContentOffset: CGPoint, withScrollingVelocity velocity: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
    // item's setup ......
    // ...................

    let finalPoint = CGPoint(x: newOffsetX, y: proposedContentOffset.y)

    // Select cell in collectionView by Default
    let updatePoint = CGPoint(x: newOffsetX, y: 180)
    let indexPath = collectionView!.indexPathForItem(at: updatePoint)
    self.collectionView!.selectItem(at: indexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: [])

    return finalPoint
}
```

But it doesn't work. I have to manually select the cell by swiping up, which is pretty unclear for user. How should I select the cell without tapping and swiping?

Any advice will be appreciated

UPD: After a night without a sleep finally managed it thanks to Vollan

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    let position = 2 * scrollView.contentOffset.x / collectionView.superview!.frame.width

    selectedItem = Int(round(position))


}
```

UPD: But the best just got better. Converted answer from linked to Swift version

> This would be better code because it's cleaner and easier to read, all the content offset calculation is superfluous:

```
 NSIndexPath *centerCellIndexPath = 
[self.collectionView indexPathForItemAtPoint:
[self.view convertPoint:[self.view center] toView:self.collectionView]];
```

> This would also be the correct representation of what you're actually
>   trying to do:
>   1. Taking the center point of your viewcontroller's view - aka visual center point
>   2. convert it to the coordinate space of the view you're interested in - which is the collection view
>   3. Get the indexpath that exist at the location given.

So it takes 2 lines:

```
 let centerPoint = self.view.convert(view.center, to: collectionView)
 let indexPath = collectionView.indexPathForItem(at: centerPoint)
 -> save media[indexPath.row]
```

And that was basically what Sachin Kishore suggested, but I didn't understand him at first

I kind of like the idea with dynamic indexPath but it takes some rounding, which is not reliable. So I think `convert` and `indexPathForItem` is the best here

Comment: just asking finalPoint is the cell which is Displayed at centre ?

Comment: I guess so) I can paste the full method if it'll help

Comment: I can suggest using https://stackoverflow.com/a/19266183/6080920 , get the CGPoint of cell that is located in centre of CollectionView and convert that CGPoint into IndexPath and then you will get what you want in output

Comment: This doesn't solve your solution, but i would personally choose to have a  dynamic `indexPath` as such `var currentIndexPath: IndexPath`. Which you update (item?) value on when you swipe left or right (+ or -)

Comment: @iOSGeek saw that, tried it, no luck. I managed to grab an index path by accessing `collectionView.subviews.first?.center`, but those paths were completely random as I saw in console

Comment: @MaxKraev When do you access `centerCellIndexPath`? I have noticed that it returns `nil` only when you reach the end of the `collectionView` and it's to recycle from the first cell again.

Comment: @Vollan but how can I update it by Int if I'm scrolling for example from 1 to 5 item in one go? You mean in `scrollViewDidScroll`?

Comment: @staticVoidMan tried it from different places, from `cellForRow`, from my custom methods, from `viewDidLoad`. Btw I switched off the infinite scroll

Comment: @MaxKraev Sorry, i thought you were stepping when you where scrolling, but then yeah, in `scrollViewDidScroll` you can update `indexPath` every time you moved X points. `ceil(scrollView.contentOffset.x/(cellSize+spacing))` or something like that. Note that it's not tested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were to put the logic into the `scrollViewDidScroll` you can update an `indexPath` dynamically.

```
let position = scrollView.contentOffset.x/(cellSize+spacing)
currenIndexPath.item = position
```

This should give you the current cells indexPath at all times.

Comment: You know, that worked) Thank you, You made my day. Just need to straight up the numbers

Comment: Glad it did. Interesting layout you have going on there. i like it.

Answer (score 1):

```
func viewIndexPathInCollectionView(_ cellItem: UIView, collView: UICollectionView) -> IndexPath? {
    let pointInTable: CGPoint = cellItem.convert(cellItem.bounds.origin, to: collView)
    if let cellIndexPath = collView.indexPathForItem(at: pointInTable){
        return cellIndexPath
    }
    return nil

}
```

call this function on button action and pass the button name , collection view name on this function

Comment: Hm, what should I pass for cellItem? I tried `collectionView.subviews.first` but it gives me the same random indexPaths

Comment: pass button sender here

Comment: like 
@IBAction func clickOnSeeAllButton(_ sender:UIButton) {
        guard let indexPath = viewIndexPathIncollectionview(sender, collectionview: collectionview)

Comment: I got `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)` on this

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24337791/exc-bad-instruction-code-exc-i386-invop-subcode-0x0-on-dispatch-semaphore-dis?rq=1

Comment: Checked the outlets, everything's connected